# Problems with data.map in React

Tags: reactjs

I've got an array of links which I need to display in a two-column table. So I'm using a .map function in render() to extract the array of links and then in the return statement for that function I'm creating the rows/columns. The problem is that each element in the array is repeating in both columns. I've only been working with React a short time and any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
const allLinks = this.props.links.map((link, index) => {
   return (
     <tr key={index}>
        <td className="links"><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>{link}</a></td>
        <td className="links"><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>{link}</a></td>
     </tr>
   )
 });
```

Comment: What do you want to appear in each column and what is currently happening? You realise that you're currently displaying two identical columns right?

Comment: Yeah I realize it I just thought maybe there was some way I could reference each successive {link} so they wouldn't repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create chunk of your array so that it gets converted from 
say `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]` to `[["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7"]]`
and then implment nested map like

```
const chunk = (arr, chunkSize) => {
    var arrays = []

   while (arr.length > 0) {
       arrays.push(arr.splice(0, chunkSize));
   }

   return arrays;
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       const data = chunk(this.props.links, 2);
       const allLinks = data.map((linkSet, index) => {
       return (
         <tr key={index}>
            {linkSet.map(link => {
                 return <td className="links"><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>{link}</a></td>
            })}
         </tr>
       )
     });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm getting an error saying "a is not defined" when I put the chunk code inside of render and an error saying "Unexpected token" when I put it before the render().

Comment: My mistake, it should be arr.slice , also chunk function can be generic and should be part of the React component, move it outside of the React component definition

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try this now!

Comment: Installed the code and the chunk function is definitely working ... I did a console log and got the output, but nothing is appearing in the table.

Comment: @CHays412m sorry for the inconvenience, I wan't returning anything from inside the inner map function, check the updated answer